# Add multiple products in cart programatically magento 2

Tags: cart, addtocart, magento2.3, shopping-cart, programmatically

I am trying to add multiple products in cart programmatically.  This below code is working properly but I need to set quantity dynamically. If quantity is not set that product to be skipped without adding in cart.

```
   <?php
$count = 0;
$cartItems = array();
$objectManager = MagentoFrameworkAppObjectManager::getInstance();
$_childProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);

foreach($_childProducts as $simpleProduct)
    {

    // echo '<pre>' , var_dump($simpleProduct->getData()) , '</pre>';

    $sku = $simpleProduct->getSku();
    $count++;
    $stringSku = '"' . $sku . '"';
    if ($simpleProduct['jasani_color'] == $tmp['value_index'])
        {
        $sql = "select * from inventory_stock_4 where sku =" . $stringSku;
        $result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
?>
        <td>
                <?php
        echo $option_label = $result[0]['quantity'] ?>
                <input  type="number" min="0" max="1000" pattern="[0-9]*" id="qty" name="qty"  />
                <script>
            var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value; 

<?php
        $qty = "<script>document.write(qty)</script>" ?>  
    </script>
        </td>


    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])): ?>


    <?php
            $cart = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
            $product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($simpleProduct->getId());
            $params = array();
            $params['qty'] = $qty;
            $params['product'] = $simpleProduct->getId();
            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            $cart->save();
            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            $cart->save();
            if (count($_childProducts) == $count)
                {
                header("Location:magento_controller/");
                exit;
                }

?>

            <?php
        endif; ?>

        <?php
        }

?>
</tr>

        </tbody>
        </table>

        <form method="post">
        <input class="cart-btn-custom float-right" type="submit" name="submit"/>
        </form>


        <?php
endif; ?>
</div>

<?php
}

?>
```

I can't assign a form tag before the quantity input tag because It is inside a loop. So that I cannot assign this quantity to cart quantity.
I need this quantity to be the quantity given by the user in the multiple text box. The below image clarifies my question.

[image]

I need to enter this submit box with the assigned quantities like image above.

Comment: please format the code. it's hard to read

Comment: I formatted the code pls check @PhilippSander

Comment: @PhilippSander, here is the same issue, please look into it, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274172/quote-id-is-empty-when-inserting-multiple-records-into-cart-in-magento2